# JSF disabled CommandButton is clickable and could submit form after being enabled by firebug

Tags: html, security, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF page with a form and a disabled CommandButton. Now it's possible to enable the disabled button by HTML-Browser manipulation (such as Firebug) and execute the action behind the button.

Is it possible for JSF to prevent such tampering scenarios (At least for disabled input fields a submit should fail).

Is there a built-in feature of JSF to prevent such issue or should I provide custom a solution please?

Comment: What JSF impl/version? Is the `disabled` attribute hardcoded or dynamic? Can't reproduce on Mojarra 2.2.7, at least not with a hardcoded `disabled="true"`. It should also not be possible as per [`shouldDecode()` check in button's `decode()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.7/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/ButtonRenderer.java). Only if it's dynamic like `disabled="#{some condition}"` and the condition is request based, then it's indeed possible to tamper that if the condition is broken, but that's more a bug in webapp's code than in JSF.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @BalusC . My JSF implementation is apache myfaces jsf 2.0.2. Problem could be reproduced by both hardcode and dynamic.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty ancient! More than 4 years old already. Why don't you use the most recent version?

Comment: The version is specified by out customer and you know that customers always have different requirements some of what could never be imagined. We could only upgrade only if they ask in future. @BalusC

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason. Thanks to @BalusC! the reason is in the JSF implementation apache myfaces jsf 2.0.2.
From the source code of the `decode()` [method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/2.1.1/org/apache/myfaces/shared_impl/renderkit/html/HtmlButtonRendererBase.java#HtmlButtonRendererBase.decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Cjavax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) here, we could find that the implementation will not determine whether the button is disabled or read-only before `queueEvent()`. This provides the possibility to tamper that.